# How to exclude maven dependencies?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a question about exclusion of maven dependencies. Consider the following

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
```

I am trying to achieve a transition from Spring 3.0.6 to 3.1.0 . Spring security 3.1.0  had a dependency on spring-security-web version 3.0.6 which in turn had a dependency on spring-web 3.0.6. I need to bring it all to 3.1.0. So I exclude spring-security-web from Spring security, have a separate dependency for spring-security-web 3.1.0 which in turn excludes the spring-web 3.0.6 version and I provide a separate spring-web 3.1.0 version. This work but I feel there would be a much easier approach. I tried putting an exclusion for spring web under Spring security but it did not work.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can utilize the [dependency management mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

If you create entries in the `<dependencyManagement>` section of your pom for `spring-security-web` and `spring-web` with the desired `3.1.0` version set the managed version of the artifact will override those specified in the transitive dependency tree.

I'm not sure if that really saves you any code, but it is a cleaner solution IMO.

Comment: I'll have to make do with this now . I hope the Global exclusions may make it easier ..

Answer (score 24):

Global exclusions [look like they're being worked on](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Global+exclusion+of+artifacts), but until then...

From the [Sonatype maven reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html) (bottom of the page):

> Dependency management in a top-level POM is different from just
> defining a dependency on a widely shared parent POM. For starters, all
> dependencies are inherited. If mysql-connector-java were listed as a
> dependency of the top-level parent project, every single project in
> the hierarchy would have a reference to this dependency. Instead of
> adding in unnecessary dependencies, using dependencyManagement allows
> you to consolidate and centralize the management of dependency
> versions without adding dependencies which are inherited by all
> children. In other words, the dependencyManagement element is
> equivalent to an environment variable which allows you to declare a
> dependency anywhere below a project without specifying a version
> number.

As an example:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

It doesn't make the code less verbose overall, but it does make it less verbose where it counts. If you still want it less verbose you can [follow these tips](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/optimizing-sect-dependencies.html) also from the Sonatype reference.

Comment: Thanks for this . +1 for the Global exclusion thing and reference .

Comment: See this issue : [Global dependency exclusions - MNG-1977](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-1977)