# How to combine Spring libraries that depend on different Spring versions?

Tags: spring, maven, dependency-management

I would like to use both spring-amqp and spring-data-mongodb in a Maven project. Spring-amqp depends on Spring 3.0.7 whereas spring-data-mongodb depends on Spring 3.1.2. The end result is that I have packages from both Spring 3.0.7 and 3.1.2 in my depdendency tree, and this appears to cause problems at runtime.

How should I resolve the issue? Manually add direct dependencies with a specific version to my project from either for all of the transitive dependencies of both spring-amqp and spring-data-mongodb? Recompile one or both to depend on a common Spring version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excluding Maven dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119055/excluding-maven-dependencies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [dependencyManagement](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) section of POM. Once you specify artifact versions there, maven is forced to use them in that module and it's children.

Comment: So basically specify versions of all the transitive dependencies of both spring-amqp and spring-data-mongodb in dependencyManagement of my project?

Comment: Personally I would run `mvn dependency:tree`, see bad dependencies (for example I want to use 3.1.2) and specify them (bad dependencies) in dependencyManagement section with implicit 3.1.2 version. No need to touch dependencies section or smth else. Maven will use 3.1.2 automatically.

Comment: I think that's what I just said :)