# Use Richfaces with MyFaces

Tags: maven, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I am trying to upgrade a web application using MyFaces 1.1 to a current version (presumably 2.2).

In the current state, the application also uses Richfaces. Specifically richfaces-api, richfaces-impl and richfaces-ui are included in version 3.1.6.GA via Maven. When deploying the constructed war file, I get the following error in the logs:

```
Both MyFaces and the RI are on your classpath. Please make sure to use only one of the two JSF-implementations.
```

Inspecting the dependency tree generated by Maven, I can see that richfaces-impl and richfaces-ui both depend on jsf-api and jsf-impl. I presume these are the components of the RI/Mojarra that the error is referring to, is that correct?

If this is the case, is there a way to tell Richfaces to use the already imported myfaces-api and myfaces-impl instead?

I am new to JSF and so might have gotten this wrong, so sorry if the question is very ignorant (I read through a whole lot of JSF tutorials and posts here on stackoverflow explaining JSF, which helped a lot, but it still is quite overwhelming to me.)

Comment: Just exclude unwanted dependencies from maven, there's a lot of questions about that on SO, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119055/excluding-maven-dependencies

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem.