# How to exclude lib from war package

Tags: java, maven

does anybody know how to exclude specific lib from packiging to .war

I have a following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intel.mtwilson</groupId>
    <artifactId>mtwilson-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

mtwilson-client-2.0.3.jar in WEB-INF then contains a library (javax servlet), which causes some troubles with application server. Is there a way how to exclude this specific lib from packaging? I can not exclude whole jar by setting provided tag.

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119055/excluding-maven-dependencies

Comment: @Peeve , was you able to exclude the Jar from built?

Comment: Yes I am able to exclude whole jar, but the goal is to exclude just a specific library which is opened in that jar, not to exclude the Jar itself as whole.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you need to do to exclude maven including the above jar in WAR is to mark it as `provided`.

so now your above dependency will now look like below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intel.mtwilson</groupId>
    <artifactId>mtwilson-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Note:** `provided` will not add particular JAR it to the war but will add a class path to the final war after build, which can cause some run time faults if you actually happen to miss the JAR somehow at deployment.

**2nd** thing you can do is to use `<packagingExcludes>` configuration parameter.

The syntax in POM.xml is like:

```
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/mtwilson-client-2.0.3.jar</packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
```

You can visit [Apache Maven Doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html) on exclusion of a particular jar.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but the goal is to get rif of specific library, which is opened in that JAR, not to exclude whole JAR itself.