# Maven installing multiple versions of the same dependency

Tags: java, maven

Maven plugins (maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1 and maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3) seem to be downloading multiple versions of the same dependency (plexus-utils) when running mvn clean package, even if I specify the latest version of plexus-utils in the dependencies.  This doesn't cause any errors, but any version of plexus-utils prior to 3.0.16 is vulnerable to command injection.  Is there a way that I can stop this from happening?

EDIT: As per the suggestion below I tried including an exclusion, but I think this is only supported for dependencies and not plugins.

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: You can exclude dependencies from maven, take a look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119055/excluding-maven-dependencies

Comment: Are you able to specify the exact version you want using the `version` tag?

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt I am doing this, but the plugins are downloading about 10 other versions

Comment: Right... this could be tricky. Especially if you have a parent POM, or other such stuff...

Comment: I would just stop worrying about this ... even if a Maven plugin has a vulnerability, I would not really bother because Maven is just a build tool.

Comment: If you found a plugin which is using an older version please file a ticket for the appropriate plugin so the Apache Maven Team can upgrade it and make a new release ....

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot exclude dependencies for plugins (as you can with other dependencies), you can specify the exact version that will be used for a particular plugin.

If you have a parent POM, or any other linked POMs, you may need to add this to each plugin or dependency where this is used:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Even after specifying a version for the dependency within the plugin, it seems to still download the old versions to my machine and ignore the version I gave it...

Comment: Correction: it was ignoring it because the version I specified was already downloaded.  It will download the version I specify along with the versions the plugin was previously downloading

Comment: You may need to run `mvn dependency:tree` (or similar) to find all the places these dependencies are being loaded from. If you have a parent POM, it will be tricky, and you will need to comb through it carefully.

Comment: I ran `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins` and can see the tree here. Does this work for nested dependencies because plexus-utils seems to be a part of another dependency within the plugin's dependencies?

Comment: I'm asking this because even after specifying the version for just one plugin, I get `[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile)  ---
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.pom` in the logs

Comment: I strongly discourage to change the versions of dependencies for plugins cause you don't know which versions has been used (except you take a look into the code) . Also you might cause several issues based on changing the dependency versions

Comment: And I agree completely with @khmarbaise If you really have a requirement to upgrade this library, you will also need to upgrade ALL of the other plugins/dependencies/whatnot that use the "old" version -- in some cases, this may not be feasible, as some packages may not have upgraded yet.

Comment: One more thing is: You do not control the updates/release of the plugins...

Answer (score 0):

For me i have just specified below maven build plugin,

```
spring-boot-maven-plugin
```

and i forced my version

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                        <version>1.14</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

But still it was showing the older library version for "plexus-utils" and "commons-codec".

Then looking at jenkins logs, it was actually running other plugin like

1. maven-surefire-plugin
2. maven-install-plugin
3. maven-compiler-plugin

So i need to add these plugin and forced my dependency in each.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                        <version>1.14</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```